# ExpressJS Middleware Composition

Tags: express, middleware

I'm working on a project which has a quite simple endpoint:

```
app.get('/transactions', 
    listTransactions(connectionPool), 
    addUser(connectionPool), 
    sendTransactions);
```

We get a list of MySQL rows, merge user-data into the response, and send it back to user. My question is, is there a "commonly accepted" place to store the response of `listTransactions` (in this case)? Do I store it on the `req` object?

Comment: I tend to use [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals), although that _does_ get exposed to views (which in most cases isn't an issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take.  I think you're abusing middleware in this case. The middleware is better at decoding, authenticating, etc.  I think your example has reached the point where it would make a lot of sense to wrap these things in a function like so.

```
app.get('/transactions', function(req, res, next){
    var transactionPromise = listTransactions(connectionPool)
      .then(function(transactions){
        return listTransactions(transactions, connectionPool);
      })
      .then(function(listedTransactions){
        return addUser(connectionPool);
      })
      .then(function(addUserResponse){
        res.send(addUserResponse);
      });

    transactionPromise.catch(function(error){
      res.status(500).send("Something went wrong: " + error.toString());
    }
}
```

I use promises here, but this could easily be done with something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) as well.  This approach does a few things:

1. Allows you to handle errors at the router level, rather than inside each function.  If you think about it, should a function called `listTransactions` really know how to respond to a server request?
2. In combination with the first point, it allows for better reusability by removing the dependency on the `(req, res, next)` signature.
3. Testability.  Now you can test all the individual pieces without a reliance on the previous middleware, or a specific `req` format.

My 2¢.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah this is what I was initially thinking (using lodash / Ramda and chaining or, as you suggested, Promises), but I thought by using middleware this would be more easy to get into for any dev familiar with ExpressJS when inheriting this project.

Comment: Interesting.  Why do you think this approach would be more difficult to understand?  It seems to me you wouldn't have to know hardly anything about Express with just using regular old functions.